# error refreshing Developer provisoning profile in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting error refreshing provisoning profile in xcode .
Moving from xcode-> prefreneces->account->choosing team-> view details-> refresh,

I get error as shown in following screenshot. It was working fine till yesterday and all of sudden it started crashing when i try to click refresh button. It generates same error when i try to refresh in xcode 5 too. All I have done different from yesterday is that I have added new UDID, but, as far as I know this is not cause for error.

The same error also generates when I try to fetch team profile trying to build IPA from xocde 6 as well.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is server error. I did nothing, but next day, it started working itself. So, it was definitely apple server error.